Opencv white screen on android not able to access camera python kivy
Trying to make a python kivy app for android using OpenCV but I keep getting a white or black screen with whatever I try. Here are my requirements file, buildozer.spec file, relevant code, and error log on android studio.
Requirements.txt:
appdirs==1.4.4
build==1.2.2.post1
buildozer==1.5.0
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
colorama==0.4.6
Cython==3.0.11
distlib==0.3.9
docutils==0.21.2
filelock==3.16.1
idna==3.10
Jinja2==3.1.4
Kivy==2.3.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivymd==1.1.1
MarkupSafe==3.0.2
numpy==2.1.3
opencv-python==4.10.0.84
packaging==24.2
pexpect==4.9.0
pillow==10.4.0
platformdirs==4.3.6
plyer==2.1.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
Pygments==2.18.0
pyjnius==1.5.0
pyproject_hooks==1.2.0
python-for-android==2024.1.21
requests==2.32.3
sh==1.14.3
six==1.16.0
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==2.2.3
virtualenv==20.27.1

Buildozer.spec file:
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,pillow,plyer,opencv,pyjnius,numpy


# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = INTERNET, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA

Error Log:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.530  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: Could not open OpenCV camera
2024-12-06 01:45:53.530  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error code: <class 'cv2.error'>
2024-12-06 01:45:53.530  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Available cameras: 
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Version control:               unknown
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Platform:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Timestamp:                   2024-12-06T04:42:42Z
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Host:                        Linux 6.5.0-44-generic x86_64
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Target:                      Android 1 aarch64
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      CMake:                       3.27.4
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
2024-12-06 01:45:53.531  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Configuration:               Release
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    CPU/HW features:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Baseline:                    NEON FP16
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    C/C++:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C++ standard:                11
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C++ Compiler:                /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  (ver 14.0.6)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C++ flags (Release):         -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -fdiagnostics-show-option -Qunused-arguments -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C++ flags (Debug):           -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -fdiagnostics-show-option -Qunused-arguments -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-limit-debug-info   -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C Compiler:                  /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
2024-12-06 01:45:53.532  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C flags (Release):           -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -fdiagnostics-show-option -Qunused-arguments -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      C flags (Debug):             -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -fdiagnostics-show-option -Qunused-arguments -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-limit-debug-info   -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Linker flags (Release):      -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -L/home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build -lpython3.11  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Linker flags (Debug):        -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -L/home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build -lpython3.11  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      ccache:                      YES
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Precompiled headers:         NO
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Extra dependencies:          dl m log
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      3rdparty dependencies:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    OpenCV modules:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Disabled:                    java java_bindings_generator world
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Disabled by dependency:      -
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Unavailable:                 python2 ts
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Applications:                -
2024-12-06 01:45:53.533  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Documentation:               NO
2024-12-06 01:45:53.534  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Non-free algorithms:         NO
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Android NDK:                   /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b (ver 25.1.8937393)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Android ABI:                 arm64-v8a
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      NDK toolchain:               standalone: /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      STL type:                    c++_static
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Native API level:            21
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Android SDK:                   /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk (tools: 6514223 build tools: 36.0.0-rc1)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      android tool:                /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/android
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    GUI: 
2024-12-06 01:45:53.535  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Media I/O: 
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      ZLib:                        /home/nate/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/libz.so (ver 1.2.12)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.6-62)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      HDR:                         YES
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      SUNRASTER:                   YES
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      PXM:                         YES
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      PFM:                         YES
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Video I/O:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Parallel framework:            pthreads
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Other third-party libraries:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Python 3:
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Interpreter:                 /home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 (ver 3.11.5)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.536  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Libraries:                   /home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build/libpython3.11.so
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      numpy:                       /home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/numpy/core/include (ver undefined - cannot be probed because of the cross-compilation)
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      install path:                /home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Python (for build):            /home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Java:                          
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      ant:                         NO
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Java wrappers:               NO
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I      Java tests:                  NO
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I    Install to:                    /home/nate/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/opencv/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/opencv/build/install
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  -----------------------------------------------------------------
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  
2024-12-06 01:45:53.537  5553-5580  python                  org.test.myapp                       I  

Relevant Code:
import cv2



from kivy.app import App 

from kivy.lang import Builder #building files correctly

from kivy.uix.button import Button #for the buttons

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout # for the layout (there are different types of layouts in kivy this is just the most basic one)

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout # for non dynamic layout so the buttons dont move for camera page

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen #for the screen manager to track which screen is being shown 

from kivy.uix.label import Label # for the label like headers 

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget # adds widget for each of the classes

from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown # adds dropdown widgets

from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle # adds color to the circle

from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture #used for OpenCV image data

from kivy.core.window import Window # Sets the background color for app

from kivy.uix.camera import Camera  #Kivy's built-in Camera widget

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup #For dialog window for popups when needed

from kivy.uix.image import Image #Widgets for displaying selected images

from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty # control text values

from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex # color translating from hex to rgba

from plyer import filechooser #From plyer library for image selection

from PIL import Image as PILImage #Python Image Library

from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont #Python Image Library

from kivy.clock import Clock #Used to capture frames form OpenCV Camera

import os #Python module for operating system interactions

import numpy as np #Used for handling image data from OpenCV's numpy arrays

from kivy.utils import platform







if platform == "android":



    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission #NOT AN ACTUAL ERROR ON ANDROID



    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.CAMERA, Permission.INTERNET])


class CameraPage(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(CameraPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    

        self.cap = None  # OpenCV VideoCapture

        self.image_cache = None

        self.frame_event = None

        self.current_frame = None # Captures the current frame



    # Start OpenCV camera when user is in the camera page

    def on_enter(self, *args):

        self.start_opencv_camera()



    # Stop OpenCV camera when user exits the camera page

    def on_leave(self, *args):

        if self.cap:

            self.cap.release()  # Release the camera

            

            print("Camera has been released.")



        if self.frame_event:

            self.frame_event.cancel()  # Cancel frame update



    # Start OpenCV camera

    def start_opencv_camera(self):

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Useing camera index 0 for default camera

        if not self.cap.isOpened():

            print("Error: Could not open OpenCV camera")

            print("Error code:", cv2.error)  # This might provide more insights into the error

            print("Available cameras:", cv2.getBuildInformation())

        else:

            print("OpenCV camera started.")

            # Schedule the update of camera frames by 30 FPS

            self.frame_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_camera_feed, 1.0 / 15)



    # Update the Image widget with the camera feed

    def update_camera_feed(self, dt):

        if self.cap:

            ret, frame = self.cap.read()

            if not ret:

                print("Error: Failed to capture frame.")

            else:

                self.current_frame = frame  # Store the current frame

                # Convert BGR frame to RGB

                buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()

                texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')

                texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

                self.ids.camera_feed.texture = texture



    # Capture image using the current frame from OpenCV

    def capture_opencv_image(self):

        if self.current_frame is not None:

            # Convert OpenCV frame (BGR) to PIL Image (RGB)

            pil_image = PILImage.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(self.current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))



            # Save to cache directory

            cache_dir = './image_cache'

            if not os.path.exists(cache_dir):

                os.mkdir(cache_dir)

            cached_image_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, 'captured_image.png')

            pil_image.save(cached_image_path)

            self.image_cache = cached_image_path



            print(f"Image captured and cached at: {cached_image_path}")

        else:

            print("Error: No frame available to capture")



    # Function that opens gallery works for windows and should work for android

    def open_gallery(self, *args):

        # Opens the file chooser to select images

        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.display_image)



    # Display the selected image in a popup

    def display_image(self, selection):

        if selection:

            # Cache for the selected image

            self.image_cache = selection[0]

            # Create/open popup

            image_popup = ImagePopup()

            image_popup.ids.img.source = self.image_cache

            image_popup.open()



    # Cache the selected image

    def cache_image(self, instance):

        # Checks if cache location exists

        if self.image_cache:

            cache_dir = './image_cache'  # Cache directory

            if not os.path.exists(cache_dir):

                os.mkdir(cache_dir)  # Create cache location if does not existing



            # Select a location/path for the cached image

            cached_image_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, 'cached_image.png')

            try:

                with open(self.image_cache, 'rb') as source_file:

                    with open(cached_image_path, 'wb') as dest_file:

                        dest_file.write(source_file.read())



                print(f"Image cached at: {cached_image_path}")

            except Exception as e:

                print(f"Error caching the image: {e}")

        else:

            print("Error: No image selected for caching")

I've also tried testing on a physical android device and still no luck.
